# Twilio SMS Sending issue on T-Mobile and Sprint

Tags: php, sms, twilio, twilio-api

We are facing very critical issue in Twillio SMS API from last two to three days. We have noticed that Twilio SMS is not receiving in some telecommunications companies.

Verizon & At&t were receiving the SMS.

Metro PCS,T-Mobile & Sprint did not.

Comment: Can you please steps to reproduce and code you have used?

Comment: This isn't really a coding issue, so you are best placed to take this up with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). If you share with them the message SIDs that were not delivered they will try to track down what happened to the messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Messages were showing Delivered in the twilio console, but the messages were not physically being delivered.  The messages we were sending had some text with some line breaks and also a URL.  I had to strip out the URL into a second message, then all worked fine.